# Match an alpha string with regex or nothing at all

Tags: regex

I am using the following regex patern: `^([a-zA-Z])*`

It successfully matches only alpha strings like this
`hello`

But when I add a number to the string like this `he3llo` it matchs only `he`.

**How can I tell it to not match anything at all if the whole word is not alpha**

P.S: I am experimenting with it on http://www.regexr.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add a `$` to the end

```
^([a-zA-Z])*$
```

it now means match the start of string followed by 0 or more a-z followed by the end of a string

i would change the `*` to a `+` also

Comment: Why would you change the `*` to `+` ?

Comment: So at least 1 char is matched currently an empty string will match with *

Comment: Thanks! that made sense!

Answer (score 2):

You need the end of string anchor, `$` as well.

```
^([a-zA-Z]*)$
```

This will match only alpha characters or an empty string.  With your current regex it only needed to match zero or more alpha characters from the start of the string.

Answer (score 1):

Additional to guys answer you can also use word boundaries. Since anchors will limit you only one word.

For example, if you use this regex:

```
^([a-zA-Z]+)$
```

You will match only a word like this:

**[Example](http://regex101.com/r/gA7zN5/2)**

[image]

But if you use word boundaries with this regex. You can match multiple words:

```
\b([a-zA-Z]+)\b
```

**[Working demo](http://regex101.com/r/gA7zN5/1)**

[image]